# Sitecore 7 - Content editor error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, content-editor

I'm working with Sitecore 7.0 rev 131127 and when I tried to go to the Content Editor I'm getting the following error:[image]

But when I try to go to other modules such as Marketing Center, it is working.

I tried the following changing following value to false on Sitecore.Social.config but it didn't work for me.

```xml
<!-- Is Profile updating at user login functionality enabled. -->
<setting name="Social.ProfileUpdating.EnableProfileUpdating" value="true" />
```

Can anyone advise on this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a configuration issue if I'm not mistaken namely your `Lucene Index Configrations` files within the `App_Config/Includes` folder. Most likely the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file or a custom one created in your solution.

Usually you see these sorts of errors when a `TypeConverter` is missing from the config, as you can see its referencing the Typeconverter in the `StackTrace`. E.g. For the index to correctly convert `DateTime` this line is added to the `DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file. Confirm the following line is in your `*.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file(s)

```xml
<converter handlesType="System.DateTime" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

It's also worth identifying which `Field` is causing the error. Perhaps a new field has been added recently to a template or the raw value in a `DateTime` field is not in the correct format for a `DateTime` Sitecore stores its dates in `ISO 8601` formatted i.e. `yyyyMMddThhmmss`

Comment: As Jonathan states here it will be related to DateTime conversion while searching. It's worth noting that Out of the box - Sitecore 7 Content Search does not store dates as datetimes and only stores the date part, this may be related to the issue - http://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/01/30/indexing-datetime-fields-sitecore-7-content-search/